# AngularJS CamelCase with bind and $apply explanation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm relatively new to directives and I have this piece of code that I've put together from a few different sources. Firstly I am trying to change the directive to CamelCase, so the directive's name will be something like myResize but I can't seem to do it. I know angular does normalisation so I know on my div it should be my-resize and on my directive it should be myResize but that doesn't work?

Also, can someone explain exactly what the bind scope.$apply function is doing? I thought a $watch alone would update scope.adjustForm when scope.getWindowDimensions changes but apparently that is not the case. The code is working correctly, I'm just not sure why.

```
<div id='landingWrapper' ng-class='{"centerForm": adjustForm}' resize></div>
```

---

```
.directive('resize', function ($window) {
  return function (scope, element) {
    var w = angular.element($window);
    scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
        return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() };
    };
    scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        var windowHeight = newValue.h;
        var formHeight = element[0].offsetHeight;
        if (formHeight > windowHeight) {
            scope.adjustForm = false;
        }
        else {
            scope.adjustForm = true;
        }
    }, true);
    w.bind('resize', function () {
        scope.$apply();
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: scope.$apply() updates your bindings

Comment: Why doesn't that happen automatically with $watch? When I use $watch in a controller, rather than a directive, it seems to work that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked couple of things:

1. When you define the directive on your JS file, you should use camel-case (`myResize`), whereas on your HTML you should use dash (`my-resize`). If it doesn't work for you, something else is wrong.
2. Every DOM element under the main angular directive (ng-app) has a scope. Directives may or may not introduce their own isolated scope - that is - scope that only elements underneath their tree we'll be exposed to their variables. This way, a change on a certain element (such as value-changed) doesn't have to propagate to all elements in the DOM (performance!! & memory!!), but rather only to the one on the same scope (you can of course share variables between scopes). Because of this mechanism, when any change occurs on a scope, angular can notify all the need to be known on the scope that something has been changed. But the only way for angular to know that something has changed, is if a $digest() cycle has started (`$apply()` triggers `$digest()`) which forces angular to go through all of the "current" scope and see if something was changed.
   (The main thing -) jQuery itself (or any non-angular framework for that matter), doesn't natively update angular (calls $digest()) and therefore you must do it manually (by calling `$apply()` or `$digest()`) whenever an event has happened on jQuery.

Comment: 1) There are 3 places the directive name is being used. In the HTML and twice in the directive. If I use 'my-resize' in the HTML then 'myResize' in both places in the directive, it doesn't work. However, if I use 'my-resize' in the HTML, then 'myResize' when defining the directive and then just 'resize' when I use w.bind(), everything works correctly. What the heck is going on there?

Comment: 2) So $watch in a directive doesn't natively call a $digest cycle when the variable being watched changes? You need to manually do it? Is that what 'w.bind' is doing? It's telling Angular to perform $apply when w changes?

Comment: 1) Why twice on the directive (JS file) only once..
2) Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/j831wvz3/ - try resizing the window

Comment: 1) I developed my code with this fiddle as a reference: http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/ - is this code not written well? The author references the directive name twice.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you for the information. I am happy to accept your answer. So the name of the event isn't actually important in my code? I could say w.bind('flippyfloo'...) and it would be okay?

Comment: Of course it is important! It is there to decide which event to bind on the window (resize is only one of many available events).
You can however, if desired, add a namespace to the event: w.bind('resize.myResize') this will help later on remove this specific event by w.unbind('resize.myResize')-- P>S> use w.on() rather then w.bind() (bind  is deprecated.\

Comment: Oh I see now. The 'resize' string is referring to a specific event. I thought it was just some label I was arbitrarily defining. Thanks, I was a little confused.